# Edit part of the fields?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following model.

```
public class M
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
    public int C { get; set; }
    public int D { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

The Asp.Net Mvc 4 page need only edit one column. And I had to put `@Html.HiddenFor()` for all other columns - otherwise the database column for B, C, D.... will be reset to 0s. Is it a way to avoid it?

```
@model MyMvc.Models.M

@using (Html.BeginForm()))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.A)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.B)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.C)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.D)
    ......
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just put a hidden field for Id and handle the others in your action method like this:

```
public ActionResult SaveM(M m)
{
    var mToEdit = db.find(m.Id);
    mToEdit.A = m.A;
    db.SaveChanges();
    //.......
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`HiddenFor` just generates hidden field, but this never ensures that value will not be edited. Simple  F12 click and anyone can edit value with developer tools. Instead, you should create ViewModel with that single field and check everything on server side

```
public class EditMViewModel
{
    public int A { get; set; }
}
```

And something like this in controller action

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id, EditMViewModel m)
{
    var someObject = LoadFromDb(id);
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        someObject.A = m.A;
        SaveToDb(someObject)
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```